# Given two points, find a third point on the line

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have two points `A (x1,y1)` and `B (x2,y2)` that are given as an input to the program. I have to find a third point `C` that lies on the line `AB` and is at a distance `10` away from the point A.

I can easily get the slope of the line but that doesn't give me the full equation for the line. Even if I get the full equation, I am not sure using this equation, how would I find out a point that is `x` distance away from A.

Any suggestions on how to approach this?

Comment: Do you mind if I give a language-agnostic solution? If you don't, please tag `[algorithm]`, not `[C++]`

Comment: @Jan Dvorak: Editted the tags. In fact, a language agnostic solution would be better for me.

Comment: Even then, it's quite easy. What have you tried?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are always two points on each line:

- get the vector from `A` to `B` (subtract the coordinates)
- normalize the vector (divide by its length; pythagorean theorem)
- multiply the vector by 10 **or** -10
- add the vector to `A` to get `C`

Note that if `A==B`, the line is not defined, and this algorithm causes a division by zero. You may want to add a test for equality at the beginning.

Comment: I was thinking of the solution in terms of finding an equation and then substituting a point that is `10` away from A and satisfies the equation as well, but wasn't reaching anywhere with this. I had a small question that popped up with the above solution. How does subtracting and normalizing the diff of A and B vectors give the direction?

Comment: @Cipher Multiplying a vector doesn't change its direction. The vector still points in the direction from `A` to `B` after it is normalized and scaled. The fact that the vector `A-B` points from `A` to `B` (and thus in the direction from `A` to `B`) follows from the definition of additive inverses.

Comment: @Cipher Clarification: scaling by a negative amount does change the direction, but not the line it lies on. Multiplying a vector by zero produces the zero vector.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the sine or the cosine (times 10) of the angle of the line to get the horizontal or vertical distance of the point that is a distance of 10 from a given point. A shortcut is to use the horizontal or vertical distance divided by the direct distance between the points to get the sine or cosine.

Comment: @JanDvorak Yes, but dy/d is simpler. Or is it dx/d? I always forget which is which!

Comment: `dy/d` is derivation of y over something. `dy/dx` is the slope of the line (which may be infinite). `atan(dy/dx)` produces the correct angle if vertical lines are handled correctly.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. dx/d = cosine, dy/d = sine, where d is distance between points. It's a cheap way to get those without worrying about singularities, except for the zero-length lines you mentioned.

Comment: My algorithm is more performant but your approach may be easier to understand - and that's what matters unless you're doing heavy math.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using vectors like this:

Let D = the difference between B and A (D = B - A)

Then any point on the line can be described by this formula:

```
point = A + Dt
```

where t is a real number.

So just plug in any value for t to get another point. For example if you let t == 1 then the equation above reduces to point = B. If you let t = 0 then it reduces to point = A. So you can see that you can use this to find a point between A and B simply by let t range from 0 to 1. Additionally if you let t > 1, you will find a point past B.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

You can see from the image that your given points are x1,y1 and x2,y2. You need to find an intermediate point at a distance 'R' from point x1,y1.

All you need to do is to find θ using

`Tan  θ = (y2-y1)/(x2-x1)`

Then you can get the intermediate point as  (R * cos  θ),(R * Sin  θ)

I have drawn this assuming positive slope.

Going on similar lines you can seek a solution for other special cases lile:

i. Horizontal line
ii. Vertical line
iii. Negative slope

Hope it clarifies.

Comment: +1; You should be able to handle all four cases with one piece of code.

Comment: @JanDvorak Once he has calculated value of theta, he can write `if else` conditions based on values of theta for different kind of cases. I just wanted to give an idea that it can be done in this way rather than writing the complete code with all the conditions. I think if he will get the idea, he will be able to proceed. And thanks, I have marked my other post for deletion.

Comment: Ageed. An optimisation phase should merge all cases into one, though.

Answer (score 0):

I have done the calculation in Andengine using a Sprite object. I have two Array List x coordinates and y coordinates. Here i am just calculating using the last two values from these two array list to calculate the third point 800 pixel distant from Your point B. you can modify it using different values other than 800. Hope it will work.The coordinate system here is a little different where (0,0) on the top left corner of the screen. Thanks

```
private void addExtraCoordinate(CarSprite s) {
int x0, y0, x1, y1;
float x = 0f, y = 0f;
x0 = Math.round(xCoordinates.get(xCoordinates.size() - 2));
x1 = Math.round(xCoordinates.get(xCoordinates.size() - 1));
y0 = Math.round(yCoordinates.get(yCoordinates.size() - 2)) * (-1);
y1 = Math.round(yCoordinates.get(yCoordinates.size() - 1)) * (-1);

if (x1 == x0 && y1 == y0) {
    return;
} else if (y1 == y0 && x1 != x0) {
    if (x1 > x0) {
        x = (float) x1 + 800f;
    } else
        x = (float) x1 - 800f;
    y = Math.round(yCoordinates.get(yCoordinates.size() - 1));
} else if (y1 != y0 && x1 == x0) {
    if (y1 > y0) {
        y = (float) Math.abs(y1) - 800f;
    } else
        y = (float) Math.abs(y1) + 800f;
    x = Math.round(xCoordinates.get(xCoordinates.size() - 1));
} else {
    float m = (float) (yCoordinates.get(yCoordinates.size() - 1) * (-1) - yCoordinates
            .get(yCoordinates.size() - 2) * (-1))
            / (float) (xCoordinates.get(xCoordinates.size() - 1) - xCoordinates
                    .get(xCoordinates.size() - 2));
    if (x1 > x0) {
        x = (float) ((float) x1 + 800f / (float) Math
                .sqrt((double) ((double) 1f + (double) (m * m))));
    } else
        x = (float) ((float) x1 - 800f / (float) Math
                .sqrt((double) ((double) 1f + (double) (m * m))));

    if (y0 > y1) {
        y = (float) ((float) Math.abs(y1) + 800f / (float) Math
                .sqrt((double) (((double) 1f / (double) (m * m)) + (double) 1f)));
    } else
        y = (float) ((float) Math.abs(y1) - 800f / (float) Math
                .sqrt((double) (((double) 1f / (double) (m * m)) + (double) 1f)));
}

xCoordinates.add(x);
yCoordinates.add(y);
```

}